# Kendo MVC DropDownListFor does not bind selected value to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

```html
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.ServiceID)
  .OptionLabelTemplate("#=optionLabel#")
  .ValueTemplate("#=Code#(#=Rate#) - #=Description#")
  .Template("#=Code#(#=Rate#) - #=Description#")
  .DataTextField("Code")
  .DataValueField("ServiceID")
  .DataSource(d =>
  {
    d.Read(read =>
    {
      read.Action("GetServiceRepository", "Service").Type(HttpVerbs.Post);
    });

  })
  .Events(e => e.Change("onWorkOrderJobServiceChange"))
  .HtmlAttributes(new { required = "required" })
  .OptionLabel(new { optionLabel = Resources.Wording.SelectOne, ServiceID = 0, Rate = 0, Code = "", Description = "" })
)
```

I have an dropdownlist as above, and would like to bind the selected value to model's `ServiceID` field (which is of type `int`)

However, no matter which item I select, the `ServiceID` field is always null! It is not even of nullable type `int?`!

Why is the happening and how can I achieve what I am trying to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kendo DropDownList has **[ValuePrimitive](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#configuration-valuePrimitive)**. By default, it is false, and selected item returns Text and Value pair.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.ServiceID)
  .ValuePrimitive(true)
  ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, and it works! Just one thing confusing me, so what does .DataValueField() means? I thought it is defining which field is used as the selected value, but seems the selected value is always (Text, Value) pair?

Comment: Ideally, if we set DataValueField, we should get value instead of pair. Unfortunately, it doesn't. I agree that it confused me at first too.